# How to make a fixed HTML header scroll horizontally with CSS?

Tags: html, css, header

I have found this html code for making a HTML fixed header:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>NavBar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="logo">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Apps</a></bli>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>Hello again</h2>
        <h3>And Again!</h3>
    </hgroup>
    <article>
        <section>
            <p>Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo     Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo </p>
        </section>
                    <section>
            <p>Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo </p>
        </section>
                        <section>
            <p>Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo </p>
        </section>          <section>
            <p>Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo Testo </p>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

This is the style.css file:

```
        body {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:12px;
    }
    #navigation {
            position:fixed;
            display:block;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height:35px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
            background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.8);
            color:rgba(1,1,1,0.8);
            border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }

    .center {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}

    div.logo {display:inline-block;

                     }

    .logo h1 {
            display:inline-block;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        color:white;
    }

    ul, li {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
    }
    #navigation ul {
            list-style: none;
            float:right;
    }
    #navigation ul li {
            display:inline;
    }

    #navigation a {
            font-size:14px;
            padding: 0 15px;
            color:white;
            text-decoration:none;
    }

    #navigation a:hover {
            color:grey;
    }
    #content {
            width:800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top:80px;
    }
```

The problem is that when I zoom-in the page, I only see the  element with  the "Logo" text, and I cannot scroll horizontally to see the links of the header while scrolling. 
Just try this code and you'll know what I mean. How can I make the fixed header scroll horizontally?

Comment: Can you please create a js bin/fiddle ?

Comment: I've created this fiddle for the OP: http://jsfiddle.net/FQ4LC/

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions on how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed elements usually don't scroll, they are just not made for it as they are completely out of context for the whole site. I would think about using `position: absolute` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/FQ4LC/8/

Comment: Hmm... nice. But the header is hidden when one scroll vertically. Nevertheless, it's a nice entry point for a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up this property in CSS that is hosting all of the content that you want to make scroll. 'overflow-X: scroll',

Comment: I have put that 'overflow-x:scroll;' inside my #navigation id style, but I get another scrollbar inside the div, and this is not what I want. I just want to scroll the fixed navbar horizontally with the browser's scroll. Do you have any other idea to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.center {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

into

```
.center {margin: 0 auto;}
```

Edit: With this solution the header won't scroll but the links won't disappear.

Edit 2: JavaScript (jQuery) solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $("#navigation .center").css("maxWidth", $(window).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but I would like to keep all in the center when I zoom out. Is there another way?

Comment: I've made some progress using `#navigation { position:device-fixed; /* ... */ }` but that's still not a working solution.

Comment: Yea, this is not a working solution, cause the navbar loses its fixed position if you scroll the page vertically... I cannot figure how can I resolve this problem, kinda really simple problem I guess...

Comment: I cannot fix this with pure css. The jQuery solution (see edit 2) works for me.

Comment: where should I place that JQuery?